# UPNP/DLNA Control Point

Tags: java, android, upnp, dlna

I'm working on an android UPnP/DLNA app. I have a control point working where I can stream files from media server to renderer. I can pause/play and stop the file during playback but I cannot seem to figure out how to integrate a seekbar into the control point to show the progress of the playing file and be able to interact with the seekbar. I am using the Cling Java library to create the app. If anyone has any examples that could help me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

I've tried to implement the SubscriptionCallback example and subscribe to LastChange

```
SubscriptionCallback callback = new SubscriptionCallback(service, 600) { // Timeout in seconds

                 public void established(GENASubscription sub) {
                     System.out.println("Established: " + sub.getSubscriptionId());


                 }
                 @Override
                 public void failed(GENASubscription sub, UpnpResponse response, Exception ex) {
                     System.err.println(
                         createDefaultFailureMessage(response, ex)
                     );
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void ended(GENASubscription sub, CancelReason reason, UpnpResponse response) {
                     // Reason should be null, or it didn't end regularly
                 }

                 public void eventReceived(GENASubscription sub) {
                     System.out.println("Event: " + sub.getCurrentSequence().getValue());


                               try {
                                   lastChange = new LastChange(
                                           new AVTransportLastChangeParser(),
                                           sub.getCurrentValues().get("LastChange").toString()
                                   );


                               } catch (Exception ex) {
                                   log.warning("Error parsing LastChange event content: " + ex);
                                   return;
                               }

                     Map<String, StateVariableValue> values = sub.getCurrentValues();
                     StateVariableValue status = values.get("Status");
                     System.out.println("Status is: " + status.toString());
                 }

                 public void eventsMissed(GENASubscription sub, int numberOfMissedEvents) {
                     System.out.println("Missed events: " + numberOfMissedEvents);
                 }
                @Override
                protected void failed(GENASubscription arg0,
                        UpnpResponse arg1, Exception arg2, String arg3) {

                }
            };

            upnpService.getControlPoint().execute(callback);
```

Then I try to get the duration of the current playing track:

```
System.out.println("Duration: "+lastChange.getEventedValue(0, AVTransportVariable.CurrentTrackDuration.class).getValue());
```

but this returns a NullPointerException.

Any ideas???????

*********************UPDATE************************

I have been trying to implement Seek() but have not had success.

I have my seekbar and listener but it it keeps failing when I drag the seekbar to a new position.

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) 
        {
            Log.i("SEEKTIME", "time:" + arg1);
            upnpService.getControlPoint().execute(new Seek(service, SeekMode.REL_TIME, arg0.toString())
            {
                @Override
                public void success(ActionInvocation invocation)
                {
                    //super.success(invocation);
                    Log.i("SEEKSUCCESS", "success seek");
                }
                @Override
                public void failure(ActionInvocation arg0, UpnpResponse arg1, String arg2)
                {
                    Log.i("SEEKFAIL", "fail seek");
                }
            });
        }
```

Any suggestions why this would be failing

Comment: Hi, currently, I'm searching for a tutorial about stream m3u8 file to DLNA player from Android but still have not found any good starting point yet. Could you please give me any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must poll the renderer for this kind of information (see [AVTransport spec chapter 2.3.1](http://upnp.org/resources/upnpresources.zip)). The spec encourages polling every second, but you can easily jam up a real hardware renderer (for which DLNA is still rather a fashionable pain in the a** than a vital part of the design). Our established practice is to send `GetPositionInfo()` request every 2-3 seconds and treat the returned `RelativeTimePosition` value only as an adjustment to locally running timer. For the seekbar sizing you also need the total length of current media. Ideally the renderer will tell you automatically when you subscribe to `AVTransport.LastChange`. I don't know Cling specifically but a quick look shows promising example in `controlpoint.SubscriptionCallback`. Unfortunately with real devices, `LastChange` often doesn't tell you anything much. Either the values are not there at all or have a constant inert value. So you will need to poll the `GetMediaInfo()` again and use `MediaDuration` value.

As for interaction, `Seek()` is your friend, ideally with parameters of `Unit = REL_TIME` and `Target` = your desired time offset. Be aware that a real world renderer may not be supporting this unit (mode) of seeking. Perhaps it supports only TRACK_NR in which case the seekbar is essentialy read-only for you. Again Cling should be able to tell you allowed values of `A_ARG_TYPE_SeekMode` for the particular renderer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was wondering if you could help me with Seek() I have added some code in the edit which shows I am trying to set the seekbar to a new position and then call play from that position. It keeps failing when I drag the seebar position.

Comment: Please accept this one answer and create new question. Your original question was "how to integrate seekbar and be able to interact with it" which you figured out. Now you are one level lower, having device specific problems. In the new question, say what specific DMR are you testing against and attach its DeviceDescription.xml. It may be absolutely possible that the device does not support REL_TIME seekmode.

Comment: Sorry about that. New Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900315/upnp-seek-and-seekbar-for-android-application